# Trying to read individual strings from Xml file

Tags: xml, vb.net

I am trying to read the individual values of Lat, Long, and Alt from the xml file below using visual basic. The format for the xml is different from what I've previously worked with. I can pull out elements from the file, but I'm trying to read just the individual values for Lat, Long, Alt, etc. I haven't been able to figure out how to do that with XmlReader or LINQ.

Sample Code:

```
Dim xelement As XElement = XElement.Load("D:\GAHR_KSAv1_1_1.xml")
Dim entries As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = xelement.Elements()
For Each employee In entries
Dim lla_tracker As List(Of String) = employee.Descendants("ActingPos").ToList()
Console.WriteLine(employee.Element("ActingPos"))
Next employee
```

File:

```
<Entry MC="11" Time="0.00" ActName="SCR_ON">
   <ActingPlat ID="1"/>
   <AgainstPos Lat="24.5399" Lon="46.7704" Alt="567"/>
</Entry>
```

Comment: VBA is not the same language as VB.NET - fixed your tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try xml linq

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Module Module1
    Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Sub Main()
        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(FILENAME)

        Dim againstPoses As List(Of XElement) = doc.Descendants("AgainstPos").ToList()

        For Each againstPos In againstPoses
            Dim lat As Decimal = CType(againstPos.Attribute("Lat"), Decimal)
            Dim lon As Decimal = CType(againstPos.Attribute("Lon"), Decimal)
            Dim alt As Decimal = CType(againstPos.Attribute("Alt"), Decimal)
        Next againstPos
    End Sub

End Module
```